# Why is "c'est" used in this sentence and not "est"?

Tags: grammaire

> Pour rester en forme, la chose la plus importante à faire, *c’est* d’avoir une alimentation saine.

Would it still be correct if *est* was used instead ?

---

Also, I would like other examples where it is better to use *c'est* instead of *est*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *est* would have been correct but without a preceeding comma.

> *La chose la plus importante à faire est d’avoir une alimentation saine.*

Note that both *la chose* and *à faire* do not serve much purpose in these sentences so might be removed.

> *Pour rester en forme, le plus important, c'est d'avoir une alimentation saine.*
>
> *Pour rester en forme, le plus important est d'avoir une alimentation saine.*

Answer (score 2):

Les deux donnent la même information.

La version avec *c'est* renforce la seconde partie.

**Toute phrase de ce type peut donner lieu à ce *renforcement*:**

L'élément **est** l'autre élément. => L'élément, **c'est** l'autre élément.

Il est aussi possible de faire ce renforcement avec un COD, un COI, un CC ...

Je mange une pomme. => C'est une pomme que je mange.

Il lui parle. => C'est à lui qu'il parle.

Il va à la piscine. => C'est à la piscine qu'il va.

Comment: Dans les [clivées](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/618.html), ce ne serait pas plutôt la première partie qui serait *mise en relief* ?

Comment: @GAMPUB lien très intéressant. C'est bien la partie "c'est bien la partie" qui est mise en relief, donc la seconde dans les exemples précédents.