# Implicit subject of "est" rendering "c'est" unnecessary?

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes

Can one say, e.g.,

> *Est un avocat.*

to mean the same thing as

> *C'est un avocat.*

?

One can say "*È un avvocato*" in Italian or "*Es abogado.*" in Spanish, where the subject is implicitly understood to be a man. Is this never true in French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe "Est un avocat" is a grammatical sentence, although I'm not a native speaker so I can't say for sure. I've never seen a sentence like this.

I would say only "c'est" is possible here.

"Est" and "c'est" are both possible in some circumstances when there is another noun phrase that serves as the subject, but I don't think they are exactly interchangeable because they can give a different feel to the sentence. I can't describe the difference perfectly, but in general "est" has a more formal feel, and "c'est" is sometimes informal (although other times "c'est" is idiomatic and acceptable even in formal writing in this kind of context, according to jlliagre's answer here: [La contraction « c'est » peut être après un sujet ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19450/la-contraction-cest-peut-%C3%AAtre-apr%C3%A8s-un-sujet/19451))

For example, "mon frère est un avocat" and "mon frère, c'est un avocat" are both grammatical. (However, Rémi Henry notes in a comment that it would be more common to not use an article: "Mon frère est avocat". In that case, you would not use *c'est*: the subject pronoun used before "est avocat" would be *il.* So subject doubling would result in "Mon frère, il est avocat.") Note that you are supposed to write a comma before "c'est" in sentences like this.

Similar question: [Why is "c'est" used in this sentence and not "est"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17113/why-is-cest-used-in-this-sentence-and-not-est?rq=1)

Comment: In french we would say most of the time : "Mon frère est avocat"

Answer (score 1):

You can't say "Is a lawyer." in english. In french it's the same, you have to answer the question "Who (is a lawyer)?". In english you would most likely use "he/she" in french we also use the equivalent of "it/this/that" to anwser this question.

Therefore you have three different forms in french:

> Il (elle) est avocat(e).

And the one that may look odd to you(?), but is totally fine in french:

> C'est un avocat.

It is a composition of ["ce"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ce#Note) and "est" that has been contracted to "c'est".

In my opinion you should use one of firsts two if your speech focuses on the person, and the third if the focus is on the job itself. For example if a child asks "who is this guy with the strange dress?" this question obviously concerns the job and you should use "C'est un avocat." and not "Il est avocat". Even though the second is correct, it sounds a little strange in this context.

Comment: «_You can't say "Is a lawyer." in english. In french it's the same_» But one can say "_È un avvocato._" in Italian or "_Es abogado._" in Spanish, where the subject is implicitly understood to be a man. Is this never true in French?

Comment: No it's not true in french. Even if that could make sense in cases where there is no possible misunderstanding, we still never use this form. For example "sono arrivato" in italian will never translate to "suis arrivé" even though it would be totally unambiguous in french too. I guess we do that to have some kind of consistency in the written language, but it may happen to use such forms in spoken langage (but it will most likely sound childish).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem of implicit subject of a verb.

*Est* is, in the meaning of your example, acting as a **copula**.

It means that **it does not carry any meaning**. It just links two words together, Generally a subject and an attribute.

*Est* does not carry any meaning ? If you omit one of the two members then... it is not even a copula!

Hence... what does it stand for ? Nothing! What purpose does it serve ? None!

And therefore serving absolutely no purpose, if you remove the subject, **remove it as well! :

*- Qui est ce type qui vient dans sa robe noire ?*

*- **Un avocat!***

Answer (score 0):

English are French are same in this case, in contrary of Italian and Spanish.

When you write (or speak) in English, there is always something like **Subject** + **Verb** + **Complement**, in order to be able to identify each elements. So you need a subject if you have a verb in your sentence (there is a few particular case where we don't use subject, but it's rarely use).

Take an example : If I say *J'aime les oranges*

- `J'` is the pronoun `Je` contracted because verb next begins with a vowel (means `I` in English)
- `aime` is the verb (means `like`)
- `les oranges` is the complement, also named *COD* in French because we know directly what it is, and `les` is just here for numbers *but it's off-topic to explain it here* (means `oranges`)

So if do a translation in English, we have **I like oranges**, which have the same structure

About `C'est`, it's as simple as our previous example :

- `C'` is the contraction of `ce`/`ceci`/`cela` (that word differs in function of the sentence/subject), in your case, it means `ceci`
- `est` is our verb (`être` on infinitive form)
- `un avocat` is our complement, but your word can have 2 meaning :

  - a people (lawyer)
  - a vegetable (avocado)

*Yeah, in French, we love to have 2 differents things that are written the same way*

So if you don't like contraction, you can say `Ceci est un avocat`, but it looks more formal (both in write or speak)

Comment: I don't think that building your argument around the Subject + Verb + complement stuff is pertinent as, A/ It does not fit OP's example in which *avocat* is attribute. B/ There are numerous examples of S+V+C sentences in which you can omit the subject. (infinitives, imperatives...)

Comment: @aCOSwt as I know, I don't use often imperative form, because it's aggressive and didn't let us time to discuss, both in writing or speaking use. For example, we would use *Je voudrais que vous me fassiez ceci* instead of *Faites moi ceci*

Comment: So do I. But... that it not actually the problem I wanted to point out anyway.

Comment: ***C'*** is the contraction of ***ce***, not ***ceci*** or ***cela***. Change the sentence to the future to make it obvious ***c'est** un avocat* → ***ce sera** un avocat*, definitely not the derogatory ***ceci sera** un avocat*.

Comment: Note that the OP talks about a person (*avvocato/abogado*), not a fruit.

Answer (score -1):

The "c'" of "c'est" is the contraction of "ceci" or "cela" and stands for a virtual subject of the verb. It is a demonstrative one, like "this", "that"... in English.

You can't say "Est un avocat.", as you can't say "Is a lawyer." in English.

However you can have in a litterary context something like:

> Dans un bureau sombre était un avocat.

It means "there was a lawyer in a dark office" but with a more narrative tone, like if the camera was zooming from the office to the lawyer. After this sentence one would expect a description of this lawyer and this lawyer to be the protagonist of a story.

Anyway, **you can't just remove "c'" and expect the sentence to remain the same.**

Comment: *C'* is the contraction of ***ce***, not ***ceci*** or ***cela***. Change the sentence to the future to make it obvious ***c'est** un avocat* → ***ce sera** un avocat*, definitely not the derogatory ***ceci (or cela) sera un avocat***.